# NPM install package from private repository using access token from environment

Tags: git, npm, devops

I want to install an npm package from a private repository from a specific branch. I know it's possible if you explicitly specify the token in the package path, but I don't want to keep any access tokens inside of `package.json` and so I was wondering if there's a way to do this:

```
"package-name": "git+https://<github_token>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<user>/<repo>.git"
```

with `<github_token>` not directly specified in the code, but for it to be read from the environment (either .npmrc or NPM_TOKEN env variable).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

So I just figured that I can do replace in my pipeline before the installation step, like this:

```
sed -i "s/ssh:\/\/git@github.com/git+https:\/\/${NPM_TOKEN}:x-oauth-basic@github.com/g" package.json \
```

in package.json I would have:

```
    "package-name": "ssh://git@github.com/<user>/<repo>",
```